# Individual tax from dividend of Georgian Virtual Zone Company

Tags: income-tax, dividends, private-company

I am programmer. I would like to open Company in Virtual Zone of Georgia. I will be tax resident of Georgia. I do not know what tax should I pay.

I will have only clients out of Georgia. So in my opinion this is income that does not have a Georgian source.

I found info that:

> Resident individuals are exempt from tax on income that does not have a Georgian source.

https://taxsummaries.pwc.com/georgia/individual/taxes-on-personal-income

From other site this dividend will be paid in Georgia by Georgian company to Georgian tax resident and on other website I found:

> Personal Income Tax 20% for IT Virtual Zone Company

https://pbservices.ge/virtual-zone-it-company-in-georgia/

---

So total tax should be 5% of dividend paid by company and 0% by me or 5% of dividend by company and 20% of paid value paid as my personal tax?

Comment: I checked that personal tax from dividends is 0%.